# Boolean Logic and For Loops

Tags: java, for-loop, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I was wondering if those familiar with codingbat's problems might be able to help me with understanding the differences between these two solutions and why one doesn't work.
The problem:
Given a string, return true if the first instance of "x" in the string is immediately followed by another "x".

Why does the first code exit immediately after evaluating the first condition, while the other continues through the for loop? What is the difference between them?

I thought the following code would do the trick:

```
boolean doubleX(String str) {
  for(int i =0; i<str.length()-1; i++){
    if(str.charAt(i)=='x' && str.charAt(i+1)=='x')
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

However this code only evaluates true when the first x is followed by an x. However the following code does solve the problem:

```
 boolean doubleX(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == 'x') {
            if (str.charAt(i + 1) == 'x') {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first function returns `true` for a String like `"xaxx"`, where the **second** x is followed by another x, but the first x is not.

It keeps checking subsequent characters if the first x is not followed by an x, instead of stopping when the first x is reached.

Comment: I just don't understand why the second works while the first doesn't. Doesn't the second code just define the same operations using more lines?

Comment: @AzureBoredom No, it explicitly returns `false` when the first x is not followed by another x. For the first function, the condition `str.charAt(i)=='x' && str.charAt(i+1)=='x'` just evaluates to false and the loop keeps going. There is no `return false` until the end of the function, after the loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write first code as below:

```
boolean doubleX(String str) {
  for(int i =0; i<str.length()-1; i++){
      if(str.charAt(i)=='x') {
          if(str.charAt(i+1)=='x') { 
            return true;
          }
      }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Now probably you understand the difference. This first code returns 'true' for first occurrence of 'x' only if second occurrence of 'x' is received immediately at i+1. There is no 'false' return there.

While the second code always returns after first occurrence of x' as either `true` or `false`, no matter if another 'x' is received at i+1 or not.